# ASP.NET Link from Mobile Redirect to Desktop Version

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, computer-science

Basically what I have is the default.aspx page along with a few others have redirects in their CS - like so:

```
if (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true")
    {
        Response.Redirect("/mobile/index.html");
    }
    else
    {
        //nothing
    }
```

what I want to do is exactly this and it works great, but I would like to have a link from the mobile site to the  desktop site, therefore bypassing this redirect once clicked - I am no CS dev so bear with me.

Any suggestions welcome, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a QueryString (http://yourapp.com?OverrideMobileCheck=true) to the link you use from mobile and then test it in C#

```
if(Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["OverrideMobileCheck"]){
    Response.Redirect("/mobile/index.html");
}
```